# Assign one array to another as key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. One has group names the other one has group items. I want to assign group names as keys to the second array.

Example:

```
$array1 = array(
  0 => "A",
  1 => "B"
);

$array2 = array(
  0 => "a,b,c,d",
  1 => "e,f,g,h"
);
```

The second array should become:

```
$array3 = array(
  A => "a,b,c,d",
  B => "e,f,g,h"
);
```

How can i achieve this in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) as such :

```
$array2 = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use array_combine, api [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 0):

would work like this:

```
    <?php 
    $grpNames = array(0 => "A", 1 => "B");
    $grpItems = array(0 => "a,b,c,d", 1 => "e,f,g,h");
    $newArray = array();
        foreach($grpItems as $grpItemKey => $grpItems){
            if(isset($grpNames[$grpItemKey])){
                $newArray[$grpNames[$grpItemKey]] = $grpItems;
            }
        }

    var_dump($newArray);
     ?>
```